# How can I concatenate multiple values for a single identifier in SQL?

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

My Code:

```
SELECT
    o.ORDER_ID
    ,o.ORDER_DESCRIPTION
    ,o.ORDER_DATE
    ,o.ORDER_ITEM_ID
, i.CONCATENATED_ITEM_DESC

FROM ORDERS o

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i.ITEM_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(i.ITEM_ID > 1) THEN 'CONCATENATE THE DESCRIPTIONS'
    END AS CONCATENATED_ITEM_DESC
    FROM ITEMS i

)i ON o.ORDER_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
;
```

[image: This is the desired output]

I'm trying to get the description from another table concatenated.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard function is `listagg()`:

```
SELECT o.*, i.CONCATENATED_ITEM_DESC
FROM ORDERS o INNER JOIN
     (SELECT i.ITEM_ID,
             LISTAGG(ITEM_DESC, ', ') WITHIN GROUP )ORDER BY ITEM_DESC) AS CONCATENATED_ITEM_DESC
      FROM ITEMS i
      GROUP BY i.ITEM_ID
     ) 
     ON o.ORDER_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID;
```

However, many databases have other names for the function, including `string_agg()` and `group_concat()`.